# How to use the same semaphore between program executions?

Tags: c

I have a simple program that only uses one process (each time it's executed), creates a semaphore with a key that is the file's name (`ftok()` function), and then writes a line to a file. The thing is, the semaphores (in this case, 2) have to do two things: one has to guarantee that no more than two programs write at the same time, and the other has to verify that only 10 lines maximum have been written to the file. So if I execute the program and the file already has 10 lines of text, it won't write anything to it.

This is my code:

```
#include "semaphores.h"

int main() {
    int semaphoreLines = create_semaphore(ftok("Ex5.c", 0), 10);
    int semaphoreWrite = create_semaphore(ftok("Ex5.c", 1), 1);
    FILE *file;

    int ret_val = down(semaphoreLines, 1);
    if(ret_val != 0) {
        printf("No more lines can be written to the file!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    down(semaphoreWrite, 1);
    file = fopen("Ex5.txt", "a");
    fprintf(file, "This is process %d\n", getpid());
    fclose(file);
    up(semaphoreWrite, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute it the first time, `semaphoreLines` goes to 9 (as intended), locks the `semaphoreWrite` to 0 (so no other process can write to the file), then writes and frees up the latter back to 1. The process terminates. I manually tell it to run again in Terminal. However, `semaphoreLines` should be 9 so when I `down()` it, it goes to 8 and so forth. The issue is, it gets back up at 10 again. I don't want this.

Maybe it's because I'm fairly new to semaphore programming, but I thought semaphores were public if they don't get created with 0 key. With the `ftok()`, I wanted it to be public so that if I run the program again it decrements it if possible and writes, if not it displays the error code and terminates. I mean, the semaphore doesn't get removed, so the second time the program gets executed it should see the semaphore value is 9, right...?

I don't really want to fork 10 processes and have them write one by one to the file in the same program...or is that the only way to do it?

P.S. The `create_semaphore()` function is part of my `semaphores.h` header file, which contains 4 simple functions I wrote so it's easier to use semaphores instead of running all that semget, semop, and semctl stuff every time I want to work with them.

Comment: windows / linux / mac ??

Comment: This is on Mac, but it would work on Linux too.

Comment: @Lovato Can you show us how is create_semaphore implemented?

Comment: @PavanManjunath This is how it's implemented: `int create_semaphore(int k, int n_resources) {  
 key_t key = k;
    int semid;
    union semun arg;
 
 if ((semid = semget(key, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) {
     perror("semget");
  exit(1); 
 }

 arg.val = n_resources; 
 if (semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, arg) == -1) {
      perror("semctl");
   exit(1); 
 }
 
 return semid;
}`

Comment: The assignment says this: Write a program that: 1. writes a line in a text file; 2. guarantees mutual exclusion; 3. the file can only contain a maximum of 10 lines. This means if you run the program, it should not write anything if the first semaphore cannot be decremented.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is, it gets back up at 10 again. I don't want this.

If you don't want this, then don't do it. You yourself are setting the semaphore value to 10 in `create_semaphore()`. Instead, pass IPC_EXCL in addition to IPC_CREAT to `semget()`, and if that yields errno EEXIST, just return from `create_semaphore()` and skip the `semctl(SETVAL)`.